# How to use document properties as variables in an IronPython Script to Change Column Names in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am aiming to write a script (that ill run with a Action Item Button) to take use a Drop Down Property Control to select a column in my Data Table, and then change the name to whatever I type in an Input Field Property Control.

My script is simple and below and works when I type the values of the column i'd like to rename (Currently "TWO") and the new name i'd like to use "THREE"

Application.Document.Data.Tables['DataTable'].Columns['TWO'].Name='THREE'

What I would like to do is using a document property I created OldName.Property in place of 'TWO" and another document property "NewName.Property" in the place of three. I thought I had set up the script paramters correctly but I guess I haven't because they aren't working.

[image: My simple setup]

[image: Script and script paramters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using quotes (and in one case square brackets) around the property names TWO and THREE.

This worked for me:

```
Application.Document.Data.Tables['yourtable'].Columns[TWO].Name=THREE
```

where 'yourtable' is a literal string (your table name). TWO and THREE are the input parameters. If you set them to type Property you can simply select a document property and click on it to set each of them.

Comment: oh Excellent! Thank you @Gaia for the response and the clear explanation!